# Сортировка массива по значению с определенным шагом

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

У меня дан такой массив и нужно отсортировать его по значению hp с шагом 50.
как это сделать?

```
$carsArr = [
    ['manufactor' => 'Mazda', 'model' => '6', "hp" => 55],
    ['manufactor' => 'Mazda', 'model' => '3', "hp" => 65],
    ['manufactor' => 'Hyundai', 'model' => 'i30', "hp" => 120],
    ['manufactor' => 'BMW', 'model' => 'Smart', "hp" => 45],
    ['manufactor' => 'BMW', 'model' => 'X1', "hp" => 50],
    ['manufactor' => 'Lada', 'model' => 'Granta', "hp" => 170],
    ['manufactor' => 'Lada', 'model' => 'Granta turbo', "hp" => 190]
];
```

Comment: Теперь нужно объяснить что такое "отсортировать с шагом"

Comment: Грубо говоря разделить значения (0-50),(50-100),(100-150) и так далее

Comment: Так отсортировать или разделить?  Или отсортировать и разделить?

Comment: Какой результат должен быть в итоге?

Comment: Отсортировать и разделить

Comment: "Взять всё, да и поделить!"

Comment: Если с просто сортировкой я понял как разобраться, то с сортировкой и разделением не понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос конечно странно звучит, но наверное вот так

```
$carsArr = [
    ['manufactor' => 'Mazda', 'model' => '6', "hp" => 55],
    ['manufactor' => 'Mazda', 'model' => '3', "hp" => 65],
    ['manufactor' => 'Hyundai', 'model' => 'i30', "hp" => 120],
    ['manufactor' => 'BMW', 'model' => 'Smart', "hp" => 45],
    ['manufactor' => 'BMW', 'model' => 'X1', "hp" => 50],
    ['manufactor' => 'Lada', 'model' => 'Granta', "hp" => 170],
    ['manufactor' => 'Lada', 'model' => 'Granta turbo', "hp" => 190]
];
function customMultiSort($array,$field, $step) {
    $result = [];
    $sortArr = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        $sortArr[$key] = $val[$field];
    }
    
    array_multisort($sortArr,$array);
    $maxHp =$array[count($array)-1]["hp"];
    foreach($array as $val){
        for($i=0; $i<=$maxHp; $i+=$step){
            if($val["hp"]>$i and $val["hp"]<=$i+$step)
                $result["$i-".($i+$step)][] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(customMultiSort($carsArr, "hp", 50));
```

Вывод:

```
array(4) {
  ["0-50"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(3) "BMW"
      ["model"]=>
      string(5) "Smart"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(45)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(3) "BMW"
      ["model"]=>
      string(2) "X1"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
  ["50-100"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(5) "Mazda"
      ["model"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(55)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(5) "Mazda"
      ["model"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(65)
    }
  }
  ["100-150"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(7) "Hyundai"
      ["model"]=>
      string(3) "i30"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(120)
    }
  }
  ["150-200"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(4) "Lada"
      ["model"]=>
      string(6) "Granta"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(170)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["manufactor"]=>
      string(4) "Lada"
      ["model"]=>
      string(12) "Granta turbo"
      ["hp"]=>
      int(190)
    }
  }
}
```

Следующий раз задавайте вопрос более подробно и прикладывайте код со своей попыткой реализации поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

сортируем что есть, потом раскидывеем

```
usort($data, function($a,$b){ return $a['hp'] - $b['hp']; } );
$result = [];
foreach ($data as &$d) {
    $key = (int) $d['hp'] / 50;
    $result[$key][] = $d;
}

print_r($result);
```